# Bootstrap 4 not rendering in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I have updated from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 now the Razor View will not render properly as seen here in this image:

[image]

As you can see all Bootstrap styling is gone and the navbar has disappeared. This was fine with Bootstrap 3.

This is just the standard login page that comes with an MVC project, so I have not added anything fancy to it.

My bundle is as follows:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace FoodSnap
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
             "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
             "~/Scripts/respond.js"));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"));
    }       

}
```

}

In my view I have rendered as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("FoodSnap_TEST", "LogIn", "Account", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>*@
                @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>*@
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Pre-Registration", "Index", "PreRegistration")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roles", "Index", "Role")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("FoodSnap", "Index", "FoodSnap")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Review", "Create", "FoodSnap")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - FoodSnap_TEST</p>
    </footer>
</div>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I have tried numerous things including CDN's and the result is the same. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is almost a complete rewrite of Bootstrap 3 which means:

None of the Bootstrap 3 code is compatible with Bootstrap 4.

Read the docs to migrate:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/